# Remote starting a laptop in a car with sms

Tags: remote-access

I am looking for a solution where a laptop is placed in a car and I want some hardware that enables me to turn on the laptop remotely with sms or similar protocols.

What do I need for making this work?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of ways to do that:

**First method:**
Arduino with GSM connected to your laptop.
[image]
Simply your Arduino will work like a mobile with SIM card, you will send a magic packet to your Arduino over SMS and then your Arduino will turn on your laptop over serial port "if your laptop support wakeUP over USB"
check [this article](http://narzan.weebly.com/my-blog/arduino-wake-up-pc-via-usb-port) that I made on my blog about magic packets over serial port, or you can add other shield "Ethernet" if you want it over ethernet

**Second method:** connect your laptop with USB 3G adapter.
3G USB adapter can work like mobile too by changing the firmware of your adapter.

**There is two type of 3G adapter:**

**First one** only a USB with SIM slot and the firmware "the program" will be on your laptop, this type require your laptop to be ON to control it.

**Second type** 3G modem and router, you can flash your 3G portable router with dd-wrt firmware and built in a small script to make your router respond to SMS command.

Or simply connect your laptop over Ethernet to a small portable 3G router, you can wake up your laptop with magic packet. "very easy"

Comment: Can you give a link to the specific arduino needed (are they all the same?) . Just gonna order one to test it i think.

Comment: Arduino UNO R3 - and [this GSM shield] (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoGSMShield) They are all the same, but with more PINS to control more things, anyway you only need what I have mention